# Transferring arrays from c to python

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, cython

I am transferring a `double`-array from a `c`-function to a `python`-function. My code for that is:
C-Code:

```
double *compute(int size, const double a[])
{
    double* array;
    array = malloc(sizeof(double)*size);
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
    array[i] = 3*a[i];
    }
    //printf("Array in compute-function is: \n[");
    //for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        //printf("%f, ", array[i]);
    //printf("]\n");
    return array;
}
```

pyx-code:

```
cdef class ArrayWrapper:
    cdef void* data_ptr
    cdef int size

    cdef set_data(self, int size, void* data_ptr):
        """ Set the data of the array
        This cannot be done in the constructor as it must recieve C-level
        arguments.
        Parameters:
        -----------
        size: int
            Length of the array.
        data_ptr: void*
            Pointer to the data            
        """
        self.data_ptr = data_ptr
        self.size = size

    def __array__(self):
        """ Here we use the __array__ method, that is called when numpy
            tries to get an array from the object."""
        cdef np.npy_intp shape[1]
        shape[0] = <np.npy_intp> self.size
        # Create a 1D array, of length 'size'
        ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape,
                                               np.NPY_INT, self.data_ptr)
        return ndarray

    def __dealloc__(self):
        """ Frees the array. This is called by Python when all the
        references to the object are gone. """
        free(<void*>self.data_ptr)


def py_compute(int size, np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=1] a):
    """ Python binding of the 'compute' function in 'GNLSE_RHS.c' that does
        not copy the data allocated in C.
    """
    cdef double *array
    cdef np.ndarray ndarray
    # Call the C function
    array = compute(size, <double*> a.data)

    array_wrapper = ArrayWrapper()
    array_wrapper.set_data(size, <void*> array) 
    ndarray = np.array(array_wrapper, copy=False)
    # Assign our object to the 'base' of the ndarray object
    ndarray.base = <PyObject*> array_wrapper
    # Increment the reference count, as the above assignement was done in
    # C, and Python does not know that there is this additional reference
    Py_INCREF(array_wrapper)


    return ndarray
```

python-code:

```
for i in xrange(10):
    x[i] = i;

a = cython_wrapper.py_compute(10, x)
print a
```

But my result is

```
[         0          0          0 1074266112          0 1075314688          0 1075970048          0 1076363264]
```

instead of the expected

```
[  0.   3.   6.   9.  12.  15.  18.  21.  24.  27.]
```

Where is my mistake? I assume it has something to do with a problematic pointer transfer, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake here is that in the line

```
ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape,
                                      np.NPY_INT, self.data_ptr)
```

you are telling numpy that `self.data_ptr` is pointing to an array of ints and *not* one of doubles.

You can fix your code by telling numpy the correct datatype like so:

```
ndarray = np.PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, shape,
                                      np.NPY_DOUBLE, self.data_ptr)
```

and it should work as expected.

In addition to this you can simplify your wrapper code slightly as well by not having to pass in the size of the input array as it is already contained in the `np.ndarray` that you pass to `py_compute`

```
def py_compute(np.ndarray[np.double_t,ndim=1] a):
    """ Python binding of the 'compute' function in 'GNLSE_RHS.c' that does
        not copy the data allocated in C.
    """
    cdef double *array
    cdef np.ndarray ndarray
    cdef size = a.shape[0]

    # Call the C function
    array = compute(size, &a[0])

    array_wrapper = ArrayWrapper()
    array_wrapper.set_data(size, <void*> array) 
    ndarray = np.array(array_wrapper, copy=False)
    # Assign our object to the 'base' of the ndarray object
    ndarray.base = <PyObject*> array_wrapper
    # Increment the reference count, as the above assignement was done in
    # C, and Python does not know that there is this additional reference
    Py_INCREF(array_wrapper)


    return ndarray
```